# Crystal Reports Join 2 datetime fields

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report with a data source from a spreadsheet that is all the days in the year and another source that is from a database.

The first source:
 SELECT `Sheet1_`.`Date`
 FROM   `Sheet1$` `Sheet1_`

The 2nd:
 SELECT `scledbak`.`dtl_datetime`
 FROM   `scledbak` `scledbak`

I want to link the databases:
`Sheet1_`.`Date` = `scledbak`.`dtl_datetime`

But I want to have the fields to be just date, not datetime.

Can link these as a command and change the fields to date vs datetime?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cast(scledbak.dtl_datetime as date) as dtl_date FROM  scledbak scledbak
```

instead try

```
SELECT Convert(date, scledbak.dtl_datetime) as dtl_date FROM  scledbak scledbak
```

Comment: The database is a visual fox pro database.  I'm getting an error:  Function name is missing. I'm wondering if this isn't possible with this database driver?  I can't get this to work.

Comment: Im not super familiar with FoxPro but try the above edit